# biopython installation on Mac Mojave

Tags: python3, macos-mojave

I recently installed Mojave and updated to Python 3.7.
I then could not import Bio  ( biopython ) any longer, so I am trying to reinstall.

After rebuilding biopython 1.73 from scratch, using python3 setup.py build, then test, then install, I can now import Bio if my working directory is the biopython build directory. Outside of that directory, I get a module 'Bio' not found error.

suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**What worked for me was:**

First uninstall all trace of biopython

In the terminal:

- pip uninstall biopython
- pip3 uninstall biopython
- pip3.X uninstall biopython

Note: If you have python3.7 is pip3.7, python3.7.6 will still be pip3.7

Then see which python do you use, in the terminal:

- which python
- which python3

Then, the main process is:

1. **dowload manually** biopython-1.74.tar.gz 16Mb – Source Tarball from https://biopython.org/wiki/Download
2. decompress/unzip/tar biopython-1.74.tar.gz
3. in the terminal change directory to biopython-1.74 and:

   - python setup.py build
   - python setup.py test
   - sudo python setup.py install

or

- python3 setup.py build
- python3 setup.py test
- sudo ython3 setup.py install

or

- python3.X setup.py build
- python3.X setup.py test
- sudo python3.X setup.py install

DONE! https://pypi.org/project/biopython/

Answer (score 0):

I have since repaired the installation by uninstalling biopython and reinstalling. It seems that it took 2 uninstalls to clean things up.

python3 -m pip uninstall biopython

Uninstalling biopython-1.73:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BioSQL
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/biopython-1.73-py3.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled biopython-1.73

python3 -m pip uninstall biopython

Uninstalling biopython-1.73:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/biopython-1.73.dist-info/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled biopython-1.73

python3 -m pip uninstall numpy

Uninstalling numpy-1.16.3:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/f2py
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/f2py3
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/f2py3.7
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.16.3.dist-info/*
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.16.3

python3 -m pip install numpy

Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/6e/71a3af8680a159a141fab5b4d19988111a09c02ffbfdeb42175cca0fa341/numpy-1.16.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.3

python3 -m pip install biopython

Collecting biopython
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/6f/388e730f61ca76dbc89885e102d6105124151c3291e8ac0a08be51410afd/biopython-1.73-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from biopython) (1.16.3)
Installing collected packages: biopython
Successfully installed biopython-1.73